# How gmail handles file attachment?

Tags: file-io

When I select a file to attach in gmail compose screen, It automatically uploads the file to server without page refresh. I looked at the html source code via FireBug and have not seen a n iframe. How do they upload attachments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example and small write-up [here](http://www.sajithmr.com/upload-files-like-gmail/).